# Why do i get nothing back when i add more than one char to the end of this string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to get a list of consonants. However with this code, I get nothing back when i have a string longer then 1.

I have tried `toString` and `concat`, converting to an array

```
function solve(s) {
    let subStrList = [];
    let tm = "";

    for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        if(!"aeiou".includes(s[i])){
            tm += s[i];
        }else{
           subStrList.push(tm);
           tm = "";
        }
    }// For End
    return subStrList;
}

OUTPUT: [ 'z', 'd', '' ]
```

Comment: Can you provide a full input, its expected output, and the current (actual) output? You provided part of that at the bottom.

Comment: there's a typo: `tm += "";`

Comment: You're explicitly setting `tm` to an empty string; do you mean to do that?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, it looks like he is resetting his temp variable that stores consecutive consonants. However, that variable if not getting appended at the very end if the input ends in a consonant.

Comment: If there isn't an `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u` character at the end of the string you're throwing away whatever is stored in `tm` instead of adding it to `subStrList`

Comment: If that's the Codewars task, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @guijob No, that's not a typo. Please do not put technical answers/suggestions in the comments section where they cannot be adequately peer reviewed.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `tm` as an accumulator to collect a sequence of consonants, then adding the the collected consonants to the result array and resetting the accumulator once you find a vowel. One problem with this kind of algorithm is you have to handle the case where the end of the string is a consonant and now you have add whatever is in the accumulator (`tm`) to the list. For example:

```js
function solve(s) {
  let subStrList = [];
  let tm = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (!"aeiou".includes(s[i])) {
      tm += s[i];
    } else {
      subStrList.push(tm);
      tm = "";
    }
  } // For End
  if (tm !== "") {
    subStrList.push(tm);
  }
  
  return subStrList;
}
console.log(solve("zadacs"));
```

Note however, a much cleaner solution to this would be a simple regex:

```js
function solve(s) {
  return s.split(/[aeiou]/g);
}
console.log(solve("zadacs"));
```

Note: You can also use `s.split(...).filter(Boolean)` to remove empty substrings, if that's a requirement.

Comment: The second solution will add an empty string at the end, if the input is, for example, `zadacsa`. Maybe you can use `Array.filter()` to fix it.

Comment: @Shidersz To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how OP wants to handle empty strings since there doesn't seem to be any attempt to account for them in cases like `zaaadacs` either. However, I added a note about that case.

Answer (score 0):

This comes because you do not add the last collection of consonants at the end.
Try this:

```
function solve(s) {
    let subStrList = [];
    let tm = "";

    for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        if(!"aeiou".includes(s[i])){
            tm += s[i];
        }else{
           subStrList.push(tm);
           tm = "";
        }
    }// For End
    subStrList.push(tm);
    return subStrList;
}
```

Comment: Only add the last `tm` if it's not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's because you only add to the array if there is a following consonant. So just after your function is finished you have:

```
s: "zodacs"
subStrList: (2) ["z", "d"]
tm: "cs"
```

You can you add a check just before the return:

```
    ...
    if(tm.length > 0) {
        subStrList.push(tm);
        tm = "";
    }
    return subStrList;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, i had missed two cases. 1. What happens when the last letter is not a vowel and 2. what happens when the first letter is not a vowel. 
I am aware this isn't the cleanest code but its the solution i could come up with.  Thank you for all of your help.

```
function solve(s) {
  let subStrList = [];
  let subStr = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (!"aeiou".includes(s[i])) {
      subStr += s[i];
    }
    else if(subStr !== ""){
      subStrList.push(subStr);
      subStr = "";}
  } // FOR END

  if (subStr.length > 0) {
    subStrList.push(subStr);
  }
  return subStrList;
}
```